# How to input data image dataset as dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, keras, pandas-styles

I have a dataset, that contains only images. I need to input it as a dataframe.

I tried to do this with load_files function from sklearn:

data = load_files(path)

And tried to create a dataframe with output of the function above and pd.Dataframe function, but id didn't workout

The result should contain filepaths and labels as on the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZO9M.png)

Comment: What's the end result meant to be? Just image names / path? The pixel data? Something else?

Comment: @Pep_8_Guardiola
The result should contain two columns, filepaths and labels

Comment: What do you mean by labels? You need to show some actual input and expected output data or no one knows what you're really asking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [{"Filepath": str(img), "Labels": img.parent.name,
      "View": f'<img src="{img}" width="200" height="200">'} # View is optional
     for img in Path("images").rglob("*.png")] # or `*.*` if you have mixed formats
)

df.style # `.style` is optional
```

Output :

[image]

*Tree used :*

```
images
┣━━ category1
┃   ┗━━ foo
┃       ┣━━ gis_exchange.png
┃       ┗━━ stackoverflow.png
┗━━ category2
    ┗━━ bar
        ┣━━ ask_ubuntu.png
        ┗━━ stack_apps.png
```